# PC unable to ssh to Mac

Tags: ssh

I have a Windows 10 PC: 192.168.84.21
A Mac (macOS Sierra)    : 192.168.84.250
An iPhone 5s                  : 192.168.84.234
And an Apple TV            : 192.168.84.122

All connected to the same network. I know this because I have an app (Fing) on my iPhone that scans the network and shows all the devices, and all the devices pop up with the correct IP's and device names.

The Router is a [XB6-A](https://www.xfinity.com/support/articles/wireless-gateway-compare) but it's setup with Google's Wifi Mesh, which is what I connect to.

The problem: I can't ssh from my PC to the Mac.

I'm using PuTTY and here's the command I'm using:

```
pscp -r -pw <password> me@192.168.84.250:Desktop/blank.png C:Users/me/temp
```

And I'm getting `Fatal: Network error: Connection timed out`.

Diagnostics:

The PC and Mac both have their firewalls turned off.
The PC and Mac cannot ping each other.
When the PC pings the Mac this is the response:

```
Pinging 192.168.84.250 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.84.21: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.84.21: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.84.21: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.84.21: Destination host unreachable.

Ping statistics for 192.168.84.250:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss)
```

When the Mac pings the PC this is the response:

```
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
ping: sendto: No route to host
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
ping: sendto: Host is down
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
ping: sendto: Host is down
Request timeout for icmp_seq 4
ping: sendto: Host is down
...
```

Both laptops can ping the Apple TV
The iPhone is able to ping both laptops
The PC can ping the iPhone but the Mac cannot (Same output on Mac as when pinging PC)
Remote login is turned on on the Mac

Limitations:

I cannot reset the router
I cannot login to the router
I cannot connect to the internet through the XB6-A, only via the Google Wifi Mesh

Any idea why the PC cannot ssh into the Mac?

### Update

Output of `ipconfig` on PC:

```
Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 12:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : lan
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::f041:985f:3eb1:456e%6
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.84.21
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.84.1
```

Output of `ifconfig` on Mac:

```
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=1203<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TXSTATUS,SW_TIMESTAMP>
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
XHC20: flags=0<> mtu 0
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 3c:15:c2:c5:1f:ba 
    inet6 fe80::1468:65cd:5eb9:fc86%en0 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x5 
    inet 192.168.84.250 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.84.255
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
p2p0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 2304
    ether 0e:15:c2:c5:1f:ba 
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
awdl0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1484
    ether 7a:9a:4d:d0:43:93 
    inet6 fe80::789a:4dff:fed0:4393%awdl0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x7 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
en1: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 72:00:03:39:01:b0 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
en2: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 72:00:03:39:01:b1 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
bridge0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=63<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 72:00:03:39:01:b0 
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x2
    member: en1 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 8 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en2 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 9 priority 0 path cost 0
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: <unknown type>
    status: inactive
utun0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 2000
    inet6 fe80::e5b8:7dcb:fd4f:82a7%utun0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xb 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
en4: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 2e:be:08:cc:ca:41 
    inet6 fe80::c5c:a1d0:1525:3937%en4 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0xc 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect (100baseTX <full-duplex>)
    status: active
```

Comment: What is the output of `ipconfig` from a command prompt on the PC and `ifconfig` from a terminal window on the Mac?

Comment: @krubo I updated with the output

Comment: Some routers have features that isolate clients from each other. Are you able to tell us what type of router you have? Are you able to login and check if such a feature is available and is turned on? Can you mac or PC ping your iphone. I can on mine.

Comment: @DudenamedBen I provided the answers to your questions above, but for convenience, the router is a [XB6-A](https://www.xfinity.com/support/articles/wireless-gateway-compare), I cannot login to it, and my PC can ping my iPhone but my Mac cannot (get's the same result as when pinging the PC)

Answer (score 5):

To allow VNC and SSH you need to allow it in two places.

- On the Mac, open **Sharing System Preferences** pane and enable **Remote Login**. Ensure that access is allowed for **All users**.
  The status area at the right contains the SSH connection string.

[image: image1]

- To enable VNC, while still in Sharing, select **Remote Management**
  and press **Computer Settings…**.
  A drop-down pane appears in which we can select
  **VNC viewers may control screen with password**.
  Supply a password and click OK to complete the configuration.

[image: image2]

- If you still have problems connecting, disable your firewall on the Mac.
  If that solves the problem, ensure that port 22 is always open.
  To ssh from the Mac, SSH should be in the list of allowed programs in
  Sys prefs > security > firewall panel.

To test that ssh is functional, enter from Terminal
`ssh localhost` or `sftp localhost`.

You may also test if SSH and Remote Login is currently enabled by entering
`sudo systemsetup -getremotelogin`, which should answer
`Remote Login: On`.
If it is Off, this can be turned on quickly by entering
`sudo systemsetup -setremotelogin on`.

Comment: All I had to do was add access for my username under remote login. But I'll give you the bounty anyways since you helped me get there

Comment: Yes, one can be more selective, rather than allowing all users.